# R grepl: combine conditions

Tags: r, grepl

I'm new in R, and I have to check, if string contains only digits, `.` and space symbols.
My version of code is:

```
grepl("\\d+.", x)
```

But it doesn't work. I need following result:

```
str <- "0. 365" 
str1 <- "S12"

grepl("\\d+.", str) #True
grepl("\\d+.", str1) #False
```

How can I combine my conditions for `grepl` correctly?

Comment: You must also escape the period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this [regex](https://regex101.com/r/R1v8Ev/1).

```
str <- c("0. 365", "S12")
grepl("^[ \\.[:digit:]]*$", str)
#[1]  TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: No need to escape `.` within `[]`, in fact, what you have there will match a literal "\"

Answer (score 2):

You say you want to check "if string contains only digits, `.` and space symbols". You do not mention **in which order** these character types should appear. I take it that the order you are looking for is fixed: first digit, then period, then space (to judge by the fact that you've accepted @Rui's answer, which works for fixed order). If, however, the order is variable rather than fixed, then this regex would work:

Data:

```
str <- c("0. 365", ".0&0 ", "abc.12 .2", "000. ", "123", "ab.c")
```

Solution:

```
grepl("^(?=.*\\s)(?=.*\\d)(?=.*\\.)[\\s\\d\\.]+$", str, perl = T)
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

This works by asserting that (i) a white space char exists, (ii) a digit exists, and (iii) a period exists, and by allowing only the three characters to appear between start of string `^`and end of string `$`. (For a similar case see [How to match strings that only contain a character set in any order and any numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64416474/how-to-match-strings-that-only-contain-a-character-set-in-any-order-and-any-numb/64417961#64417961))