# How to match strings that only contain a character set in any order and any numbers?

Tags: r, regex

I can't seem to figure out how to match strings that contain **only** "%", and "§", and "#" in any order and repeated any number of times:

```
str <- c("%#", "#%%§§#", "§%5x#yz", "%#§", "ab§", "!#%§")
```

This pattern seems to get me close to the solution:

```
grepl("(?=[§#]*%)(?=[§%]*#)(?=[%#]*§)", str, perl = T)
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Just the last match `!#%§` isn't correct as the string does **not only** contain the character set. I see why `grepl` matches this string: because the last three characters are indeed the character set. So the remaining question is how to **limit** matches to the character set. I've tried using the anchors `^` and `$`, only to find no matches at all:

```
grepl("^(?=[§#]*%)(?=[§%]*#)(?=[%#]*§)$", str, perl = T)
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

What's the solution here?

Comment: No, matches must include all three chars and no more than those three

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use:

```
^(?=.*%)(?=.*#)(?=.*§)[%#§]+$
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/x6XxVV/1)**.

The trick is to make sure all the characters in the string are allowed characters. We do so by using `^[%#§]+$` in addition to the Lookaheads.

**Breakdown:**

- `^` - Beginning of the string.
- `(?=.*%)` - A positive lookahead to ensure that the '%' character exists.
- `(?=.*#)` - A positive lookahead to ensure that the '#' character exists.
- `(?=.*§)` - A positive lookahead to ensure that the '§' character exists.
- `[%#§]+` - Match one or more characters from the character class.
- `$` - End of string.

Comment: Yes, sure! That's it! Then `"^(?=[§#]*%)(?=[§%]*#)(?=[%#]*§)[%#§]+$"`works too but yours is obviously far more elegant and less verbose.

Comment: @Chris Yes, but since we're using the allowed characters in the character class anyway, `.` should be enough in the Lookaheads.

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann Use your approach if the strings can be arbitrary. Only use this `.*` approach if the input strings are always just `%#§` and are not too long.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach: ensure with a lookahead that the string is solely composed of your three characters and then match a string that contains three different characters using capturing groups and backreferences restricted with negative lookaheads:

```
^(?=[%§#]+$)(.).*(?!\1)(.).*(?!\1|\2).
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/GjqjlG/2).

[R proof](https://tio.run/##K/r/v7ikSMFGVyFZQ0lVWUlHQUlZVfXQ8kPLwexDy1VNK5Qrq0BsVeVDy0F0YhKEVlQGqlPS5EovSi3I0VCK07C3jQaKKMdqq2hq6GnqaWnYK8bEGCKza2JijDT1gJqBduooFKQW5SjYKoQEhbpq/v8PAA):

```r
str <- c("%#", "#%%§§#", "§%5x#yz", "%#§", "ab§", "!#%§")
grepl("^(?=[%§#]+$)(.).*(?!\\1)(.).*(?!\\1|\\2).", str, perl = TRUE)
```

Results: `[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE`

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [%§#]+                   any character of: '%', '§', '#' (1 or
                             more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $                        before an optional \n, and the end of
                             the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .                        any character except \n
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \1                       what was matched by capture \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .                        any character except \n
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \1                       what was matched by capture \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \2                       what was matched by capture \2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .                        any character except \n
```

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann If the strings may come from users, of different lengh, the `(?=[%§#]+$)` lookahead will filter out non-valid strings faster, right before triggering those lookaheads/backreferences.